# Make a smart contract track exchange rate and only accept payments of a set value

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, remix

I've made a smart contract for receiving a payment which then pays out to 2 other addresses, dividing  the total value received into 2 shares of 10% and 90% respectively. It is to be used on a website in conjunction with a paywall. I made this a little while ago and it seems to work (published on mainnet 6 months ago used on this page: http://www.linebreakrecords.com/plaintext.php not a serious store more just me learning how to use blockchain on websites). However the code I've used is basic and deprecated in places now (when I view in Remix I get warnings now about not using 'emit prefixes and 'Potential Violation of Checks-Effects-Interaction pattern' as well as 'Fallback function...requires too much gas (infinite)').

Firstly I'm hoping for recommendations of how to make this code more robust/secure and compliant with current best practice. Secondly I'm hoping for recommendations about how to make the contract only accept transactions above a certain value ($2 for example) and track the current exchange rate (so I could set the minimum value payable to $2 and have that follow the exchange rate so it stays at $2 regardless of changes in the market). I know this is pretty basic stuff and the code I'm giving here is probably primitive AF, I'm trying to learn as I go, please help if you can. Massive thanks.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.15;

contract CONTRACT1{

event senderLogger(address);
event valueLogger(uint);

address person1Adress;
address person2Adress;

function () payable { 
senderLogger(msg.sender);
valueLogger(msg.value);

person1Adress = 0x705b4e2d44be431740b11fa9ba6ace47bef8d035;
person1Adress.transfer(msg.value / 10); 

person2Adress = 0xC0BB3c8362628E152f70b602de4B7CFB41516618;
person2Adress.transfer((msg.value / 10) * 9);
} 
}
```

Comment: You want us to write a contract for you. That's too broad. I don't think anyone will answer this.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look anyway :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a bad contract but it could definitely use some improvement.  I've pointed out a few issues below, but there can always be more.  Smart Contract work requires a paranoid mindset on testing as you're working with real money and if you mess, up there is no bank to [reverse the transaction](https://www.ccn.com/parity-technologies-suggests-hard-fork-release-locked-ether/) for you (the parity example is still burned ETH and will most likely remain that way).

I hope this helps you improve and let me know if you need any more help!  If my answer fits what you were looking for, don't forget to hit the check mark so your question counts as solved.

### Tabbing ;)

- Help me out here man, it's hard to read your snippet.

### Events

- Think about what the purpose of an event is.  To alert you that something has occurred on the blockchain.
- If so, why emit two events each with only a single piece of information, when only a **single event** occurred on the blockchain.
- Also you need `emit` before your event calls in the newer versions of Solidity (https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.21/contracts.html#events) and it's allowed in older versions so might as well add it to clarify it's not a random function call.

### Constructors

- Initialize the two addresses you'll be splitting the money between in the [constructor](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.21/contracts.html#constructors) of your contract rather than each time ether is received.

### Math

- The way you split your money is scary.  Have you tested this and ensured the contract ends up with 0 Ether after each transaction?
- When dividing by 10 in a contract you can make some cool assumptions about the number that you can't normally.  For now, think of numbers in Solidity as base ten numbers with a limit on digits (it's on bits but close enough).
- So we're limited to 5 digits with no decimals in the code, but we interpret the number as 3 digits of number and 2 of decimal.  That makes `12525` 125.25.  To divide 125.25 by 10 in Solidity is to shift every digit to the right and add a 0 at the front.
- This makes `125.25 / 10 = 12.52` and `12.52 * 9 = 112.68' but`12.52 + 112.68 = 125.2`with .05 left in the contract untouched.  Over time this may build up, but either way is burnt ether as you didn't include a function that calls the`selfdestruct()` function.
- The correct way to do your math is to calculate **either** 90% or 10%.  Then subtract the result from your received amount of ether to find the other value to send.  In the above example, you'd do `125.25 - 12.52 = 112.73` and there'd be no remainder.
- And for most any smart contract work you should use [SmartMath](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol) to prevent issues with over/under flows.

### Gas Prediction

- I very rarely see this be correct so I would disregard it after you review it.
- It's often triggered by having loops in your function or something else that leaves Solidity with no clue how much gas you'll use.
- Always review it though because you never know if you have an unterminated loop or something.
- While it may have no idea how much gas your function requires, it's absolutely correct about it's warning concerning the fallback function.
- If the fallback function requires more than the minimum gas required for a transaction it'll fail and it's something no experienced contract dev would ever do so watch for it.
- My advice is not to mess with the fallback functions though, I've always found them to be a pointless feature (in that they can run code) and I never include one (making it so no [ether can't be sent to my contract](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.21/contracts.html#fallback-function) without calling a payable function).
- Instead use payable functions any time you want your contract to receive ether and perform some function afterwards.
- If you simply want your contract to be able to do all the coded stuff AND receive meaningless donations (someone just wanting to be nice) that would be a use case for the fallback function.
- But then again, if you have a fallback function someone new to ethereum may just send ether to your contract instead of calling a function and you'll take it as a donation.
- This is another reason I just would have a payable donate function that has no code and simply exists so if someone sends ether to my contract without a function call it'll tell them it's invalid.

### What you want to do

- Stackoverflow is usually against this kind of thing so try to stay away from saying what you want to do and expecting us to do it for you or explain how to do it.
- Personally that's my favorite part of programming and in larger projects I get agitated once it's just writing lines of code and all the problem solving has been done (although every problem is never solved).
- Instead ask about the parts that confuse you most about what you're trying to do.
- I'll be answering as if you asked: "So I want to only accept transactions above a certain value and have that value track to the exchange rate.  How can I track the exchange rate?"
- Just in case you don't know, rejecting ether sent to a payable transaction is as easy as having a [require](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/control-structures.html#error-handling-assert-require-revert-and-exceptions) with a false condition.
- Require is awesome because most clients can detect it before even
  sending the transaction to you, so you're not rejecting the ether but
  instead they're told by Metamask NOT to send the transaction because
  it'll fail.
- If they choose to send it, it'll still fail and send back the ether
  without you having to write any more code but the gas they sent will
  be burnt.
- In order to track to the exchange rate you really would need some sort of Oracle or decentralized exchange on Ethereum that reveals it's price API (I don't believe any exist rn).
- A much more useful way to do this would be to just set the exchange rate manually and update it daily.  You could set it up so with a click of a button your JS code interacts with any of the 1000 price APIs to get the price and then send it with a function call.
- It's definitely not a perfect solution, but getting information from outside the blockchain into the blockchain is quite the challenge.  Look into Oraclize and see what they offer that could help you accomplish your task.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! sorry it's taken me so long to get back to I was on a long holiday. OK thanks for the advice regarding the maths, they way I had it set up seems to work as far as I can tell on both main and test, but I'll definitely follow your advice as I don't want to waste ether. I've added emit prefixes and will move the addresses to the constructor to, that totally makes sense! two last things if you would be so kind....

Comment: 1. 
I get a warning: "requires too much gas (infinite). If the fallback function requires more than 2300 gas, the contract cannot receive Ether." when i deploy the contract. 
However I know it works,although does require more gas than a normal transaction, presumably due to the 2 internal transaction. Is it safe to ignore this? and if not how would you set a limit?

Comment: 2. I would like to make this contract only accept transactions of above a certain value, however i would like that value to track exchange rates, so for example it will always only accept transactions of $3 or more regardless of the current exchange rate

Comment: Don't worry about how long it took, took me a bit to see this comment as well.  I'm editing my post now to include your most recent two pieces of info.

Comment: Thanks so much!! really appreciate all the help